# ¿Como no copiar el contenido que ya existe en un archivo?

Tags: java, android

He formulado esta pregunta con el fin de una ayuda en este tema:

**He estoy tratando de crear un proceso de copiado, pero no completo, es decir, que solo actualice el contenido de un archivo con los cambios realizados en otro.**

- Explico:

He creado dos archivos txt uno con el nombre A y otro con el nombre B, ambos archivos tienen los mismos datos, hasta que mi programa altere los datos de el archivo A realizando cambios en la escritura (No borrando el contenido y escribiendo otro sino solo agregando mas contenido), y una vez que se realice estos cambios quiero que se actualicen o agreguen solo los cambios que se realizaron no todo el contenido de nuevo, solo que copie lo que no tiene o le falta.

### Mi codigo actual:

*Mi código resulto muy útil a la hora de copiar los datos de entrada a un archivo, haciendo la conversión de InputStream a File, lastimosamente no realiza esta operación que necesito*

**Mi código:**

```
    public boolean creaArchivo2(String ruta, InputStream is)
        throws IOException {

        final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(ruta)));
        byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        int bytesLeidos = 0;

        while ( (bytesLeidos = is.read(chunk)) > 0) {

            os.write(chunk, 0, bytesLeidos);
        }
        os.close();

        boolean verdadero=true;
        return verdadero;

    }
```

**Si saben como lograrlo por favor comunicármelo Gracias.**

Comment: Exceso de cursiva no ayuda en leer. :)

Comment: Ok Gracias por el dato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solamente agregas contenido a los archivos, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Despues de agregar el contenido a archivo A, te consigues el tamaño `size` del archivo B:

```
File archivoB = new File(ruta);
long length = (File) archivoB.length();
```

Luego creas un `FileInputStream` de archivo A, y buscas la posición de los datos agregados, usando [fis.skip(length)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip(long)), y lo pasas a tu método modificado, pasando `true`para `append` (esto te va abrir archivo B para agregar los datos al fin del archivo, como documentado [en la Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean))):

```
public boolean creaArchivo2(String ruta, InputStream is, boolean append)
    throws IOException {

    final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(ruta, append)));
    byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int bytesLeidos = 0;

    while ( (bytesLeidos = is.read(chunk)) > 0) {

        os.write(chunk, 0, bytesLeidos);
    }
    os.close();
    return true;

}
```